# SQL SERVER consultas utilizando check

Tags: sql-server

El ejercicio indica "en la tabla la tabla limite de importe siempre debera ser mayor a cero y no puede ser desconocido" ¿se utiliza check para este caso? ¿cómo estaría estructurado?

¿Estaría bien así?

```
add constrain UQ_limite_importe
unique(importe)
check (importe > 0) not null
```

Answer (score 2):

La idea está correcta, pero tienes un poco confundida la sintaxis. Estás tratando de hacer 3 operaciones en una sola instrucción y una de ellas no es lo que se pide.

- Empecemos por decir que es CONSTRAINT y no CONSTRAIN.
- Luego debemos recordar que hay que indicar a cual tabla pertenece el CONSTRAINT.
- Por último, separamos las instrucciones para que cada una haga lo que deben.

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla( --Esto es solo para tener un ejemplo funcional, pero debe ser tu tabla.
    importe decimal(10,2)); 

ALTER TABLE MiTabla ADD CONSTRAINT CK_limite_importe CHECK (importe > 0);

ALTER TABLE MiTabla ALTER COLUMN importe decimal(10,2) NOT NULL; --El tipo de dato debe concordar con el que tienes en tu tabla para esta columna..
```